# Why does overloading the equal operator make my object unhashable?

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I have this object:

```
class MyObject:

    def __init__(self, name: str, collections: list = None):
        self.name = name
        self.collections = collections
```

I have another class that contains a set of `MyObject`:

```
class MyObjectHolder:

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_objects = set()

    def AddMyObject(self, my_object: MyObject):
        self.my_objects.add(my_object)
```

This is working fine so far, but for some other reasons, I want to overload the equal operator for `MyObject`:

```
class MyObject:

    def __init__(self, name: str, collections: list = None):
        self.name = name
        self.collections = collections

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, MyObject):
            return self.name == other.name
        else:
            return NotImplemented
```

However, when I call the method `AddMyObject` after overloading the equal operator, I get the following error:

`TypeError: unhashable type: 'MyObject'`

Why is that so?

Comment: FROM [DOC](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__): If a class does not define an `__eq__()` method it should not define a `__hash__()` operation either; if it defines `__eq__()` but not `__hash__()`, its instances will not be usable as items in hashable collections.

Comment: Thanks, you can post that as an answer if you want me to upvote it.

Comment: Your answer is already marked with a duplicate and there's no need to another answer. Besides, it's not possible to post an answer on closed questions ;).